# How can I assign an variable to an active record object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The following code will query my db with the ST_AsGeoJSON postgis function and print the json object to the screen when in the rails console.

```
Zcta.
  select("ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_simplify(geom,500)) as my_geo").
  where(geoid10: '90210').each do |result|
    puts result.my_geo
  end
```

What if I wanted to put that content in a variable (or array, or hash for that matter)?  If i change `puts result.my_geo` to `variable = result.my_geo` and then try to use the variable later I get an error saying that the variable doesn't exist.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `map` instead of `each`

`each` will iterate over each item in your Enumerable and execute the block for it, returning `nil`. In your example, the `puts` is printing the object out to the console, but its not storing it anywhere.

`map`, on the other hand will execute the block for each element of the enumerable and return to you a *new* enumerable containing the result of running the given block on each element.

```
x = [1,2,3].map { |elem| elem + 1 }
puts x
[2,3,4]
```

In your case, you could do the following:

```
result = Zcta.select("ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_simplify(geom,500)) as my_geo")
  .where(geoid10: '90210')
  .map(&:my_geo)
```

The result of your query will now be stored as an Enumerable in the variable `result`

Comment: This did it! Thank you! Quick question though.  What is going on with the ampersand and the colon on the line `.map(&:my_geo)`

Comment: The `&` is the "proc operator" in ruby. In this case its merely shorthand for "call this method on each item." It would be equivalent to say `.map { |x| x.my_geo }`

Comment: Awesome.  Is `.map { |x| x.my_geo }` an example of a lambda?  Thanks for all the help.  It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, ruby has Procs and lambdas which are very similar but not identical. The correct/idiomatic way to refer to the `{ |x| x.my_geo }` construct that follows `map` is as a `block`. Blocks passed to functions are generally Procs, which, while very similar to lambdas, are not identical.

Comment: Right, right.  I actually meant block.  I will have to reread my resources on blocks/procs/lambdas.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Do you define your variable in the block? Then it won't be accessible outside.
define the variable outside of the block first.

Answer (score 2):

Or use `map` instead:

```
variable = Zcta.
  select("ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_simplify(geom,500)) as my_geo").
  where(geoid10: '90210').map do |result|
    result.my_geo
  end
```

Comment: Both you and thecoffman gave the same answer and it worked.  Thank you very much!